# Do i need to restart Apache after changing the settings.php file of a Drupal website?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, settings, restart

I wanted to know the answer before I make the changes on a production server:

Do I need to restart Apache after changing the settings.php file of a Drupal website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is `NO`, as it is `.php` it is not cached by Apache it is not `php.ini` or something like that, Apache is caching only its own configs and `settings.php` is `Drupal` settings